# Search pattern in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I want to select only names start with UPPER N, no lower n included.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM states WHERE name LIKE 'N%' ORDER BY id ASC;

SELECT * FROM states WHERE name RLIKE '^N' ORDER BY id ASC;
```

I also tried similar to and regex
but the results are always upper and lower N names;
what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you could just use regular `LIKE` here rather than `RLIKE/REGEXP`, as `LIKE` can express starting with a letter.  Use `LIKE` with the `BINARY` keyword to make the comparison case sensitive:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM states
WHERE name LIKE BINARY 'N%'
ORDER BY id;
```